# Should git ignore the *.pch files created by XCode?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, git, macos

Should I add *.pch files to .gitignore in XCode projects?

Answer (score 8):

No, you should not. It's not a generated file, you as a developer may (and should) modify it. The point is to put the most commonly used `#import`/`#include` directives in here. That will speed up compiling as Xcode will then precompile it and GCC will use these "cached" results when compiling other files without the need to parse and compile those includes over and over again.

I found the speedup to be especially dramatic with C++, BTW.

Answer (score 6):

To add a bit more context to the question - What files should you *consider* ignoring in a VCS?

1. Personal settings files such as *.pbxuser. These are things that contain the settings for your personal environment or workspace. Not much use to anyone who clones the repository and of marginal use if you are using a repository across machines
2. Generated files. If your project generates files then there is no point in having them in your repository because unless you are always generating them, they end up out of date. This is why you frequently see `build/` in the `.gitignore` file
3. Files that contain passwords or access tokens. Pretty obvious, really.

Put it simply. Don't ignore anything that your project requires to build. The PCH file is referenced in your project settings and you'll get a build error if it doesn't exist in the project so it really should be in the repository.

Answer (score 3):

No, they're important to the project.

They're prefix headers and will be imported to every file within the project.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use git, I use svn but the ignore settings should be the same.  When I set up a project, the only things I ignore by default are:

- the `build` directory
- `*.pbxuser` and `*.mode1v3` in the xcodeproj bundle.

Everything else (including the pch file) is something that should be under source code control (unless you add other generated files outside of build).